# How to automate testing of graphical (eclipse-based) desktop applications?

Tags: eclipse, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I need to automate testing of desktop applications based on eclipse.
Is it worthy ?
If yes, what kind of tools can I use with some well known continuous integration tools ?

Answer (score 2):

[**SWTBot**](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) is getting mature, and can be used for SWT-based Gui testing.

You can integrate those test in a Continuous Integration process, or even have them as JUnit test.

[image: Run as config]

Answer (score 2):

We use a commercial tool called [WindowTester](http://www.instantiations.com/windowtester/) from instantiations. You can buy it together with WindowBuilder (UI designer) in the RCP Developer suite. It's really good and quite cheap in my opinion.

Comment: Instantiations has been bought by Google and WindowTester is free to use without paying anything. (Not sure what exact license it is released under, though.)